# Problems with Google layers plugins

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I currently use Quantum GIS 1.7.4 at work and I have trouble to open Google layers extension. In fact, when I start QGIS 1.7.4 the following message appears and I cannot use Google layers extension.

Can you help me sort this problem out?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 147, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/JICA/.qgis/python/plugins\GoogleLayers\GoogleLayers.py", line 33, in initGui
    self.sessionid = gmaps.get_sessionid()
  File "C:/Users/JICA/.qgis/python/plugins\GoogleLayers\gmaps.py", line 21, in get_sessionid
    sessionid = t.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%s")
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Version de Python :
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Version de QGIS :
1.7.4-Wroclaw Wroclaw, 411aff6

Chemin vers Python :

```
['C:\\Users\\JICA\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:\\Users\\JICA\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\elevation', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/JICA/.qgis/python', 'C:/Users/JICA/.qgis/python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~2/Quantum GIS Wroclaw/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode', 'C:\\Users\\JICA\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\fTools\\tools']
```

Answer (score 4):

Google Layers plugin was written by a third party and is already outdated (besides, it never worked very well).

Please use **OpenLayers plugin** instead.