# Start-up error message in QGIS: Unable to load the extension GoogleLayers causes an error when calling its method initGui ()

Tags: qgis, python-2.7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problems with Google layers plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27434/problems-with-google-layers-plugins)

Impossible de charger l'extension GoogleLayers provoque une erreur lors de l'appel de sa méthode initGui()

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 173, in startPlugin
    plugins[packageName].initGui()
  File "C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis//python/plugins\GoogleLayers\GoogleLayers.py", line 33, in initGui
    self.sessionid = gmaps.get_sessionid()
  File "C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis//python/plugins\GoogleLayers\gmaps.py", line 21, in get_sessionid
    sessionid = t.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S%s")
ValueError: Invalid format string
```

Version de Python :
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

Version de QGIS :
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Chemin vers Python : [`'C:\\Users\\bruno.saphy\\.qgis\\python\\plugins\\GeoCoding', 'C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python', 'C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis//python', 'C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis//python/plugins', 'C:/PROGRA~1/Quantum GIS Lisboa/apps/qgis/./python/plugins', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\bin\\python27.zip', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\qgis\\bin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PIL', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin', 'C:\\PROGRA~1\\Quantum GIS Lisboa\\apps\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\wx-2.8-msw-unicode']ag`

Answer (score 1):

Did you upgrade from a previous version of QGIS, and have you installed extensions into that version?

I think the problem is incompatibility between the old extension and the new version of QGIS. Can you try renaming C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis (to say, C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis_original), then try running QGIS again?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to lose all your settings (by making a new folder for QGIS), try removing just this GoogleLayers plugin first. Deleting the folder `C:/Users/bruno.saphy/.qgis//python/plugins\GoogleLayers` will be enough.